# Find my number please?

Tags: mathematics, haiku

This is my first question on here so if it is not correct then please comment.

```
my number has five
the one before me has eight
which my next has nine

i am made of two
but my cousin made of ten
over a lap of home
```

What is my number?

> There are two possible answers

Hint #1

> Think of home on a global scale

Hint #2

> as people are struggling i will give an alternative to the last line
> **over an orbit of earth**

I may have made this abit ambiguous so i will add another two verses

> uinal of the mayan
> the alphabet of the bard
> next is on a die
>
> last the number K
> for my next look to SC
> i am at CA

As Requested

> My number has five being 1110010000100 which is 7300 in binary i.e. 5 zeros
> second line is 1101100010111 which is 6935 in binary
> third line is 1110111110001 which is 7665 in binary
>
> fourth and fifth lines is the relationship between base 10 and base 2 i.e. dec and binary
> and the sixth line means over a lap of the earth i.e. an orbit of earth 365 days

Apologies if it was confusing ... it sounded right in my head.

Comment: What does the phrase "over a lap" mean?

Comment: I found this on the wall.... 867-5309?

Comment: it looks like you were trying to make haiku, but "over a lap of home" and "uinal of the mayan" both have too many syllables.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the first part of the puzzle?

Comment: @gannolloy that has been done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New guess based on hints

> Twenty

my number has five

> Not sure

the one before me has eight
which my next has nine

> Don't know, letters would work if the first clue was 6 and not 5

i am made of two

> Twenty in binary is 10100?

but my cousin made of ten

> Decimal form is 20 (Obviously) or using the digits its 10,100

over a lap of home

> Something to do with orbiting earth, not sure. Orbiting earth takes about 90 minutes, can happen 15-16 times a day (less than 20?)

uinal of the mayan

> Mayan calendar has 19 months or uinals

the alphabet of the bard

> Bard's Alphabet has 20 runes

next is on a die

> 20-sided die, or 2 and 1 are next to each other on a 6-sided die (21)

last the number K

> Potassium has the atomic number 19

for my next look to SC

> Scandium = 21

i am at CA

> Calcium is 20

Comment: Agreed, it seems he is basically saying "The number is twenty, now tell me why." The first haiku still doesn't make sense in any context other than seven-segment display (too many bit changes to be related to binary), and thus only seems to work with 17, so I don't know where else to go from here.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 A comment that OP made on an earlier answer makes me think it has to do with binary

Comment: "I am made of two, but my cousin made of ten" - 20 is *2* times 10 (2 times the base in decimal), and *10* times 2 (10 times the base in binary) - i.e. made of 2 "10s" or 10 "2s"

Comment: @hyst329 that makes sense but how does it help with the over an orbit of earth thing

Comment: Two tens and ten twos isn't clarified in the second haiku - there is nothing to indicate what base we should be considering.

Comment: This is the end number i was thinking of ... i guess i made the question a little too ambiguous. @gannolloy

Comment: @Secret_Squirrel I don't think that the question is too ambiguous, just difficult to find how the clues apply to 20. Of course without knowing the connection to the first part of the puzzle, I can't say for certain whether it's ambiguous or not.

Answer (score 11):

**One answer, incomplete**

Your number is

> 17

my number has five

> On a 7 segment display, 17 uses 5 segments, like so
>
> ```
>    _
>  |  |
>  |  |
> ```

the one before me has eight

> Accordingly, 16 uses 8 segments
>
> ```
>    _
>  ||_
>  ||_|
> ```

which my next has nine

> 9 segments has 18:
>
> ```
>     _
>  | |_|
>  | |_|
> ```

i am made of two

> 17 is made of 2 digits

but my cousin made of ten / over a lap of home

> ?

Comment: Sounds like it's related to binary / decimal, purely because of the "made of 2/made of 10" comments

Comment: So 17=2^4+1 and its cousin made of ten might be 10001=10^4+1. Perhaps the "lap of home" is a 10k race or something? (But one doesn't normally do multiple 10k laps, so far as I know, and I don't understand why "of home", so this is probably wrong.)

Comment: 7 segment display is like the one on the score boards?

Comment: Yeah. I wrote the answer on mobile. I'm currently trying to get an example in my answer, but monospace blocks don't play well with spoiler tags.

Comment: Last clue: "seventy-one" has 10 letters, the "lap of home" might refer to the hyphen somehow?

Comment: "i am made of two / but my cousin made of ten" makes it sound like whatever it's counting, it's the same for each of those

Comment: Ooh, 17 is a "cousin prime" with 13.  That might be of use.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I am stumped by the second haiku as well. Even with the hint glaringly suggesting that we should be considering a day cycle (24 hours? AM vs PM? etc), I am not coming up with anything that fits the clue.

Comment: @CallumBradbury is on the right lines with [his comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32455/find-my-number-please#comment97233_32460)

Answer (score 6):

Not quite sure but are you

> 50 (counting from 100 to 0) {60 would work too, as there are two answers}

my number has five

> fifty (5 characters)

the one before me has eight

> 51 (fiftyone - 8 characters)

which my next has nine

> 49 (fortynine - 9 characters)

i am made of two

> 50 is made of two digits

but my cousin made of ten

> 50 is in the tens of decimal numbers

over a lap of home

> This I don't understand really. but I think this means that it's counting down and 0 is 'home'

Comment: This also works for 60. Maybe that's the second answer?

Comment: This relies on counting *backwards*, which doesn't seem to be indicated anywhere in the riddle.

Comment: @Matt yes indeed

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan True but maybe that could be the clue for "Over a lap of home" home being 0. but I am not sure of that

Comment: Why aren't 20 and 30 equally valid?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan because twenty has 6 characters and so does thirty

Comment: Whoops, I'm an idiot; I was mixing up your answer and Matt's! Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> 995089

my number has five, the one before me has eight, which my next has nine

> Number 995089 has the digit 5 (as one of its digits), 995088 has the digit 8, 995090 has digit 9

i am made of two but my cousin made of ten

> 995089 has 2 prime factors: 995089=241*4129, but the "cousin" 995085 (analogy with "cousin primes" - difference by 4) has 10 factors: 995085=3^7*5*7*13

over a lap of home

> On the number keyboard, 5, 8 and 9 keys(the digits which this number is composed of) are near the 7 key, aka "Home"